# Menú bootstrap se esconde cuando Fixed (menú movil)

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3

Estoy usando symfony y bootstrap, y tengo un problema con el menú, cuando hace fixed, no se porque se me esconde un pequeño trozo del menú. Se me olvidó indicar que es en menú móvil.

llevo ya unas horas echadas y la verdad me tiene amargado, a ver si alguien sabe porque.
Saludos.

La web es https://depla.es

La cuestión es que cuando bajas se esconde en la parte superior, pero cuando subes queda como debería...
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFTwk.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es necesario pegar código?

Comment: ¿Puedes reproducir el comportamiento con imágenes?

Comment: Te invito a que des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como preguntar y asi obtengas una respuesta pronta a tu problema

Comment: Estuve revisando tu página y funciona bien prueba borrando tu cache o una página de incógnito.

Comment: Debe ser problema de caché, se ve bien en iOS también (safari). Siempre tratá de hacer las pruebas en incógnito y con algún limpiador de caché a mano para que no te pasen estas cosas

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si de algo te sirve, en chrome funciona a la perfección, podrías comparar el css...

Answer (score -1):

Muchas gracias de ante mano.
Eso es porque estás usando responsive, si utilizas cualquiermodelo de movil no funciona.
Gracias